# Django Model self reference OneToOne, Can't set link while bulk_create

Tags: python, django

**Context**

Bare with me as im new to Django. I have model `Account` which I want to refer to itself, in one-to-one relationship. `Account` also has a one to Many with `Activities`.

**Goal**

1. When saving Account, save linked_account_id as a self fk
2. Being able to fetch all activities linked to BOTH accounts or just one

**Problem**
error stacks:

1. cannot save linked_account_id (string_value), it expects type `Account`

It is also possible the linked account has not yet been persisted so it wont return an entity when trying to save object by `linked_account_id`

This is the data im trying to save using `bulk_create`

```
for data in filteredList:
        account_data = {
            'accountNumber': data['id'],
            'status': data['status'],
            'last_synced': parse_datetime(data['last_synced_at']),
            'created_at': parse_datetime(data['created_at']),
            'updated_at': parse_datetime(data['updated_at']),
            'current_balance': data['current_balance']['amount'],
            'net_deposits': data['net_deposits']['amount'],
            'linked_account_id': data['linked_account_id'], (FK)
            'currency': data['base_currency'],
            'type': data['account_type'],
        }
```

this is my Model code

```
class Account (models.Model):
    accountNumber = models.CharField(default=0, max_length=20,primary_key=True)
    type = models.CharField(default='', max_length=20)
    current_balance = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=20, decimal_places=0)
    net_deposits = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=20, decimal_places=0)
    currency = models.CharField(default='', max_length=10)
    last_synced = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    is_primary = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    linked_account_id = models.OneToOneField('self', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField( default=timezone.now)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    status = models.CharField(default='', max_length=10)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.type  # Or whatever you want to represent your Account instance with

    def set_linked_account(self, other_account_number):
        try:
            related_account = Account.objects.get(accountNumber=other_account_number)
            self.linked_account_id = related_account
            self.save()
        except Account.DoesNotExist:
            print("The related account does not exist.")

    def get_all_linked_activities(self):
        if self.linked_account_id:
            return Activity.objects.filter(models.Q(account=self) | models.Q(account=self.linked_account_id))
        else:
            return Activity.objects.filter(account=self)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the main reason you better do *not* define `ForeignKey`s and `OneToOneField`s that end with an `_id` suffix, since these do *not* work with an `id`, but the `Account` directly.

With the given model, you can use:

```
for data in filteredList:
    account_data = {
        'accountNumber': data['id'],
        'status': data['status'],
        'last_synced': parse_datetime(data['last_synced_at']),
        'created_at': parse_datetime(data['created_at']),
        'updated_at': parse_datetime(data['updated_at']),
        'current_balance': data['current_balance']['amount'],
        'net_deposits': data['net_deposits']['amount'],
        'linked_account_id_id': data['linked_account_id'],  # (FK)
        'currency': data['base_currency'],
        'type': data['account_type'],
    }
```

but do yourself a favor and rename the field to `linked_acount`:

```
class Account(models.Model):
    # …
    linked_account = models.OneToOneField(
        'self', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True
    )
    # …
```

and work with:

```
for data in filteredList:
    account_data = {
        'accountNumber': data['id'],
        'status': data['status'],
        'last_synced': parse_datetime(data['last_synced_at']),
        'created_at': parse_datetime(data['created_at']),
        'updated_at': parse_datetime(data['updated_at']),
        'current_balance': data['current_balance']['amount'],
        'net_deposits': data['net_deposits']['amount'],
        'linked_account_id': data['linked_account_id'],  # (FK)
        'currency': data['base_currency'],
        'type': data['account_type'],
    }
```

---

> **Note**: Django's [**`DateTimeField`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateTimeField)
> has a [**`auto_now_add=…`** parameter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateTimeField.auto_now_add)
> to work with timestamps. This will automatically assign the current datetime
> when creating the object, and mark it as non-editable (`editable=False`), such
> that it does not appear in `ModelForm`s by default.

---

> **Note**: normally the name of the fields in a Django model are written in *snake_case*, not *PascalCase*, so it should be: `account_number` instead of <s>`accountNumber`</s>.